# Does accipio take the ablative?

Tags: ablative

In the sentence:

> ...**quō** ubi accēpit, in agrum quem arāverat magnā cum dīligentiā
> sparsit.

*quo* could either be the adverb meaning where/whereupon, or it could be the relative pronoun, assuming that accipio takes the ablative. however, the object of the previous sentence (dentes) is plural, so I am leaning towards regarding quo as the adverb here, but in that case it is confusing because both quo and ubi mean "where", so why would we have two words in a row both meaning the same thing?

Comment: Looks like a typo; I'm pretty sure that should be *quōs*, to agree, as you say, with *dentēs*, and googling for the text a lot of results actually have that.

Comment: In both my copies of Fabulae faciles, the word is quos, referring to dentes; so, as Cairnarvon says, it's just a typo.

Comment: @cnread You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This sentence appears to be from  §69 of Ritchie's *Fabulae faciles* ('The sowing of the dragon's teeth'). In both my copies of *Fabulae faciles* (two different editions), the word that is printed is *quōs*, referring to *dentīs* (= *dentēs*) and acting as the simple direct object of *accēpit*, not *quō* meaning 'where.' (And actually, in this sentence, *ubi* means 'when,' not, as you say, 'where' – even though it does mean 'where' in the previous sentence.)

> Hōc factō ad locum ubi rēx sedēbat adiit, et dentīs dracōnis postulāvit; quōs ubi accēpit, in agrum quem arāverat magnā cum dīligentiā sparsit.
>
> After this had been done, he approached the place where the king was sitting and demanded the dragon's teeth; and when he had received these, he scattered them into the field that he had plowed with great diligence.